# How to filter specific OUS from Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of users from specific OU's.

The root is `COMPANY` then `USERS`, and then there are several OU's after that, say 10. I want to only grab the users from 5 out of the 10 OU's.

How can I accomplish this?

```
  Dim ou As String = "OU=dept1,OU=Users,OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANY,DC=local"
```

I want to add dept2 to 5 in that string. It doesn't work. I can only do 1 OU at a time. How can I filter 5 dept out of 10 under the OU users?

Comment: As you've said yourself : you can't do that. You can only ever do one container (and all its subcontainers) at a time.

Comment: i know.. lol, just wondering if there was another way instead of looping again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that other than running 5 separate searches.

You can achieve similar results if the users in the different OUs are members of different groups (at least one unique group per OU). Then it will be possible to do it with a single search.